# C program crashes after calling fclose()

Tags: c, file, pointers, file-handling, fclose

I need to  write some functions in order to save Data that is saved in a doubly linked list in a XML-File. The problem I've now is, that calling `fclose()` gives me a SIGARBT Error.

```
void save()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("/home/***/CLionProjects/fussballManager/teams.xml", "wt");

    if (!file)
       return;
    fprintf(file, "<Daten>\n");
    //Save teams
    printf("%d\n", teamCounter);
    TTeam* temp = firstTeam;
    for(int i = 0; i<teamCounter; i++){
       saveTeam(temp,file);
       temp = temp->next;
    }
    fprintf(file, "</Daten>\n");
    fclose(file);
}
```

After calling `fclose`, the program receives a SIGABRT error, that doesn't occur when `fclose()` is left out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not spotting anything in the `fopen`/`fclose` calls.  Try removing the `for` and see if you still crash.

Comment: The problem lies in the code that you did not show.

Comment: Please make your example self-contained, so that we can compile it.

Comment: Can you valgrind and show us the log ?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what the `t` does in the mode string?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: with the Windows MS-provided C library, `"wt"` means "write text file" (as opposed to standard-compliant `"wb"` which means "write binary file", or standard-compliant `"w"` which also means "write text file").  On Unix, the distinction is immaterial, but the `t` on Unix may cause failure to open (invalid parameter) — or it could invoke implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: `[help-me]` You're likely stepping on the core somewhere inside `saveTeam`. Try commenting out various parts of the program until you narrow it down to a single line or statement whose absence solves the issue. Then figure out why that statement is broken. Or just use valgrinnd :)

Comment: Like the others have hinted at.  Use your debugger to inspect the value of 'file' just after the fopen().  Then again at the fclose().  Imma betting they are different...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]